# Android Graphics - clear canvas while dragging bitmap

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap

I've got one bitmap on a canvas (backgroundBitmap) that I want to remain unchanged and another smaller bitmap (draggableBitmap) that I want the user to be able to drag above backgroundBitmap.  (And I do mean "above" as in z-axis).

My thinking is that I just redraw the background with each ACTION_MOVE.  When I do this with a solid color, it works perfectly.  When I redraw the backgroundBitmap instead of the color, the backgroundBitmap remains visible but the draggableBitmap just repeats itself along the dragged path.  Why is the solid color working to "clear" the image and a bitmap won't?

**EDIT:**
Many thanks to Steve K for helping out with this.  I've updated the code below to reflect the progress so far.  The only issue at this point is that the image goes completely black after dragging begins.  Does this have something to do with the background bitmap being set to mutable?  I was getting a mutability error without it.

```
package com.example.drawing;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawingView extends View {
    // drawing and canvas paint
    private Paint canvasPaint;
    // canvas
    private Canvas drawCanvas;
    // canvas bitmap
    private Bitmap backgroundBitmap, draggableBitmap;

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setupDrawing();
    }

    private void setupDrawing() {
        canvasPaint = new Paint();
        canvasPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        BitmapFactory.Options opt1 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opt1.inMutable = true;
        opt1.inSampleSize = 4;

        BitmapFactory.Options opt2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opt2.inMutable = true;

        backgroundBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20140901_223343.jpg", opt1);

        draggableBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.draggable_image, opt2);

        drawCanvas = new Canvas(backgroundBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float touchX = event.getX();
        float touchY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // Nothing here
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                drawCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
                drawCanvas.drawBitmap(backgroundBitmap, 0, 0, null);
                drawCanvas.drawBitmap(draggableBitmap, touchX, touchY, null);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // Nothing here
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when you create the canvas, it must have a mutable bitmap to draw into. When you tried to draw backgroundBitmap to the canvas which had been initialized with backgroundBitmap as its target, it drew the backgroundBitmap, but the important thing to understand is that since it's your target drawing surface, what backgroundBitmap contains is literally the picture that you see (the sum total of everything drawn to the canvas), so when you draw it again, nothing happens. By initializing the canvas with backgroundBitmap, everything you drew to the canvas CHANGED backgroundBitmap. You need a clean surface to draw into that's not one of your sprites.

Answer (score 1):

The color has no defined boundaries, so it 'clears' the canvas by writing to every pixel. Your floating bitmap doesn't - it only redraws in the place where it is. The whole canvas needs to be redrawn, first cleared with a color, then drawn over.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float touchX = event.getX();
    float touchY = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // Nothing here
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            drawCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)
            drawCanvas.drawBitmap(backgroundBitmap, 0, 0, null);
            drawCanvas.drawBitmap(draggableBitmap, touchX, touchY, null);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // Nothing here
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }

    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, deleted the last comment.  Looks like the last argument in .drawBitmap needs to be a `Paint` object.  I tried creating one, setting the color to `Color.TRANSPARENT` and using it instead but no change.

Comment: Ok, hang on - if I set the color to anything but `TRANSPARENT` for the would-be `lastX`, `lastY` bitmap, there's a copy of the smaller bitmap that's locked in the 0,0 corner of the screen.  If I set the color to `TRANSPARENT`, it disappears.  It seems like your suggestion is working but the transparent bitmap isn't moving.  Sysout in logcat shows the lastX/Y values updating properly, though.

Comment: This still leaves a trail of `draggableBitmap`.  Your original code was fine as far as the bitmap in the corner went.

Comment: I've updated this answer. You need to draw the color before you draw your background. You're drawing every pixel anyway - you need to update them all to avoid the ghosting.

Comment: This causes the background image to be displayed initially but then the background goes black immediately after I begin dragging.  The draggable bitmap is performing properly.

Comment: I've updated the code in the original post to show the entire class.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a third bitmap.  While I confess I don't *entirely* understand how this works, I did remember reading something about the necessity of a bitmap to which all other drawings were applied in a Canvas.

`drawCanvas` is constructed with `canvasBitmap` and then `drawCanvas` is used to redraw the `bgBitmap` and `draggableBitmap`.  I'm assuming my error in the original code was that the `canvasBitmap` was constructed using the bitmap I was trying to draw over it?

```
package com.example.drawing;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawingView extends View {
    // drawing and canvas paint
    private Paint canvasPaint;
    // canvas
    private Canvas drawCanvas;
    // canvas bitmap
    private Bitmap canvasBitmap, draggableBitmap, bgBitmap;

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setupDrawing();
    }

    private void setupDrawing() {
        canvasPaint = new Paint();
        canvasPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        BitmapFactory.Options opt1 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opt1.inMutable = true;
        opt1.inSampleSize = 4;

        BitmapFactory.Options opt2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opt2.inMutable = true;

        bgBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20140901_223343.jpg", opt1);

        draggableBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.draggable_image, opt2);

        canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);

        drawCanvas.drawBitmap(bgBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float touchX = event.getX();
        float touchY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // Nothing here
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                drawCanvas.drawBitmap(bgBitmap, 0, 0, null);
                drawCanvas.drawBitmap(draggableBitmap, touchX, touchY, null);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // Nothing here
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```